# Website auto redirects to playstore app

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-4, internet

I have runkeeper installed and within the app they direct yoy to there website to create routes. However when I browse to runkeeper.com it redirects me to the playstore app automatically.  How can I force to open and browse the website?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->Applications, search for your browser and clean default settings